# What is the probability for an offspring to inherit schizophrenia?

Tags: genetics, neuroscience, human-genetics, neurology

If an European male (i.e. white) is diagnosed with schizophrenia, but an European female (also white) 2-3 years younger than the male is healthy, what is the probability that their first child will:

a) be diagnosed with schizophrenia later in life?

b) have some other mental condition?

Comment: I'm not referring to any studies and do not have background in biology/medicine. All I'm trying is to get an answer for my case, because other forums remain silent.

Comment: I'm glad that you've made it a tiny bit more specific. The site requirements are that you should show the results of your prior research - perhaps use as a springboard for your researches something like [this](https://www.nhs.uk/mental-health/conditions/schizophrenia/causes/), [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3433970/) or [this](https://www.brightquest.com/blog/is-paranoid-schizophrenia-inherited-understanding-your-parents-diagnosis/). There are indications of a genetic link, but it's far from cut and dry, more like a genetic susceptibility which might get triggered.

Comment: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27872260/

Comment: **Personal medical questions and health advice** are off-topic on Biology.SE. We cannot safely answer questions for your specific situation and you should **always consult a doctor for medical advice**.

Comment: But if scientists don't know an answer, how can a doctor know?

Comment: It may not be about "don't know" so much as "don't want to be legally responsible for" - in fact, the medical Stack Exchange is sometimes reluctant to answer personal questions about the questioner's own health (or in this case their child's), too.  But also, there is a specific medical Stack Exchange (I don't remember what its exact name is, but it'll be in the list), which may be more applicable to a question about human health than Biology.SE (which covers everything, from tomatoes to amoebas to fish), though I'm not sure.

Comment: Doesn't that probability depend on the father's age?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't directly answered this

I found a recent literature review that is relevant to this:

"Gene-Environment Interactions in Schizophrenia: A Literature Review"

by Marah H. Wahbeh and Dimitrios Avramopoulos *Department of Genetic Medicine, Johns Hopkins University School of Medicine, Baltimore, MD 21205, USA

Academic Editor: Sarah Tosato
Genes 2021, 12(12), 1850; https://doi.org/10.3390/genes12121850 (registering DOI)

This article notes that the chance of schizophrenia is more likely to arise if one of a group of conditions is present.

Conditions such as prenatal maternal exposure to some infections, childhood adversity, and cannabis use.

As far as increased chance of other disorders, the below article only uses the measure of first or second degree relatives - not chance of heritability from a parent only. This study uses the entire population of Taiwan.

"Familial Aggregation and Heritability of Schizophrenia and Co-aggregation of Psychiatric Illnesses in Affected Families"

I-Jun Chou,  Chang-Fu Kuo,  Yu-Shu Huang,  Matthew J Grainge,  Ana M Valdes,  Lai-Chu See, Kuang-Hui Yu,  Shue-Fen Luo,  Lu-Shuang Huang,  Wen-Yi Tseng  ...

Schizophrenia Bulletin, Volume 43, Issue 5, September 2017, Pages 1070–1078, https://doi.org/10.1093/schbul/sbw159

"The RR (95% CI) in individuals with a first-degree relative with schizophrenia was 3.49 (3.34–3.64) for mood disorders and 3.91 (3.35–4.57) for delusional disorders."

(RR is relative risk.)

Comment: Seems that the first article gives 80% genetic chance for a child to inherit a disease?

Comment: @mercury0114 that's the heritability - i.e. how much of the variation between individuals in having schizophrenia is caused by genetics. This isn't the same as the probability of getting it with a first-order relative has it.